# Update View by calling onDraw() without clearing previous draws?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing, redraw

I would like to draw some bitmaps. There are many bitmaps that should be drawn with the first call of onDraw() method. But it should not be redrawn every time because it needs some time. I figured out that the bitmaps are always cleared when calling onDraw() method.

Is there a possibility to add bitmaps after calling onDraw() method without redrawing existing bitmaps? A solution might be calling draw methods outside onDraw(). But I did not find a solution how to do it. What is the recommended way to add new Bitmaps to the View?

Comment: Have you tried having 2 separate Views? E.g. One is the background that contains the Bitmaps, the other is whichever one you're drawing on

Comment: I have two Views. How can I add them to the activity?